# Calculate the values of counters after applying all alternating operations

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I was trying to solve a problem from the `Codility` with a given solution. The problem is provided below:

```
You are given N counters, initially set to 0, and you have two possible operations on them:

increase(X) − counter X is increased by 1,
max counter − all counters are set to the maximum value of any counter.
A non-empty array A of M integers is given. This array represents consecutive operations:

if A[K] = X, such that 1 ≤ X ≤ N, then operation K is increase(X),
if A[K] = N + 1 then operation K is max counter.
For example, given integer N = 5 and array A such that:

A[0] = 3
A[1] = 4
A[2] = 4
A[3] = 6
A[4] = 1
A[5] = 4
A[6] = 4
the values of the counters after each consecutive operation will be:

(0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1, 1, 0)
(0, 0, 1, 2, 0)
(2, 2, 2, 2, 2)
(3, 2, 2, 2, 2)
(3, 2, 2, 3, 2)
(3, 2, 2, 4, 2)

The goal is to calculate the value of every counter after all operations.

Write a function:

class Solution { public int[] solution(int N, int[] A); }

that, given an integer N and a non-empty array A consisting of M integers, returns a sequence of integers representing the values of the counters.

The sequence should be returned as:

a structure Results (in C), or
a vector of integers (in C++), or
a record Results (in Pascal), or
an array of integers (in any other programming language).
For example, given:

    A[0] = 3
    A[1] = 4
    A[2] = 4
    A[3] = 6
    A[4] = 1
    A[5] = 4
    A[6] = 4
the function should return [3, 2, 2, 4, 2], as explained above.

Assume that:

N and M are integers within the range [1..100,000];
each element of array A is an integer within the range [1..N + 1].
Complexity:

    expected worst-case time complexity is O(N+M);
    expected worst-case space complexity is O(N) (not counting the storage required for input arguments).
```

I have a solution provided,

```
public static int[] solution(int N, int[] A) {

        int[] counters = new int[N];

        int currMax = 0;
        int currMin = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {

            if (A[i] <= N) {

                counters[A[i] - 1] = Math.max(currMin, counters[A[i] - 1]);
                counters[A[i] - 1]++;

                currMax = Math.max(currMax, counters[A[i] - 1]);
            } else if (A[i] == N + 1) {
                currMin = currMax;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < counters.length; i++) {
            counters[i] = Math.max(counters[i], currMin);
        }

        return counters;
    }
```

It seems they use 2 storage to hold and update the min/max values and use them inside the algorithm. Obviously, there is a more direct way to solve the problem ie. increase the value by 1 or set all the values to max as suggested and I can do that. The drawback will be to lower perfromance and increased time complexity.

However, I would like to understand what is going on here. I spend times debugging with the example array but the algorithm is still little confusing.

Anyone understand it and can explain to me briefly?

Comment: Wow like not a comment after whole night?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite simple, they do lazy update. You keep track at all times of what is the value of the counter that has the highest value (currMax). Then, when you get a command to increase all counters to that maxValue, as that is too expensive, you just save that the last time you had to increase all counters to maxValue, that value was currMin.

So, when do you update a counter value to that value? You do it lazily, you just update it when you get a command to update that counter (increase it). So when you need to increase a counter, you update the counter to the max between its old value and currMin. If this was the first update on this counter since a N + 1 command, the correct value it should have is actually currMin, and that will be higher (or equal) to its old value. One you updated it, you add 1 to it. If now another increase happens, currMin doesn't actually matter, as the max will take its old value until another N + 1 command happens.

The second for is to account for counters that did not get an increase command after the last N + 1 command.

Note that there can be any number of N + 1 commands between 2 increase operations on a counter. It still follows that the value it should have is the maxValue at the time of the last N + 1 command, it doesn't really matter that we didn't update it before with the other maxValue from a previous N + 1, we only care about latest.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Later, I understand it, however, your narrative helps me to comprehend the solution better, especially, I didn't know its called lazy update.  After a Google search, I find a problem lazy propagation in segment tree uses similar approaches and I can compare that to the current solution. Take care.

Comment: @Arefe yeah there are a lot of applications for it, lazy update usually means don't do something until you really need it